# Supply custom arguments to ctest with cmake

Tags: makefile, cmake, continuous-integration, googletest

From a CI perspective, I want to supply custom args to ctest (address, port, ..).
Right now, ctest is functional into my project. I am able to do:

```
cmake ..
make
make test
```

And everything works fine. But I wish to run the following:

```
cmake ..
make
make test --port 9090
```

And have "port" available into my tests. But I don't know how to handle it with cmake/make.
For information, I'm using gtest and the executable build with make is already able to handle my args. I'm only stuck to give the arguments through cmake/make.